# Problem with incorrect Freestyle rendering

Tags: rendering, freestyle

Can anyone help with why the area red is rendering incorrectly? The middle and back objects are duplicates of the front mesh. Object 1 & 2 rendered fine.

Thanks, JohnS

[image]

Comment: can you post images of your settings?

Comment: Check your properties.
If you have crease or any of the contours enabled, this could be causing that.
Can you upload the blend file?

Comment: MasterHolbytla: Which properties specifically should I be looking at? I didn't set any crease or contours, that I know of. Here is the link to the blend file: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1250" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1250/)

Comment: cegaton: which settings do you want to see? I uploaded the blend file, if you want to check it out. See the link in my reply to MasterHolbytla. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have a plane blocking that part of the frame!

[image]

Move it out of the way and render happily ever after.

[image]

[image]

The issue can be explained like this: even though you disabled the visibility for the camera, freestyle is using the geometry of the scene, and is creating a new border

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the explanation. One of the reasons that I didn't see this was I was previewing the scene in Solid & Texture mode, not Material or Rendered. BTW, is there a way to preview the Freestyle lines before final Rendering? Thanks again!